# SQL Server Error - The wait operation timed out (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, azure

I'm running a couple web applications on the same set of servers. In my logs across a number of different queries in both apps (as well as calls to the ASPState session state database) I see errors similar to the following:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) ---System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out&#xD;&#xA;  at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)  at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)  at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)  at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource 1 retry)  at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource 1 retry)  at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  at
```

One web application is fairly heavily accessed (~500 requests/sec) and one is very lightly used. I see the errors in the logs for both apps, so it seems to be an environment issue as opposed to a specific app. The server setup is 4 web servers behind a load balancer connected to 2 SQL servers in an AlwaysOn availability group. All of this is running in Azure.

Lots of searching, but can't seem to find anything that helps either identify the cause or even narrow it down to a SQL configuration issue vs Azure configuration vs network connectivity issue vs clustering issue vs ??? As best I can tell it can't connect either because it can't find the network path or the server can't accept connections. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Review the SQL Server error logs at the time the errors occur--was SQL Server running?  Was the server being rebooted?  If everything was running, is there any evidence (other than this) that there was a network disruption?  Basically the message is saying that it couldn't make a TCP connection--this could literally be thousands of things--a router or switch being rebooted, overloaded, or defective, a faulty network cable, a faulty network adapter...

Comment: SQL server is running and web apps all functioning fine (except for the .1% of users who happened to hit an error at the time). The "literally thousands of things" is where I'm stuck right now, so if anyone has tips for how to narrow down or eliminate certain pieces I'm open to it. If I find a solution I'll post it. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yeah--there is nothing from a SQL Server standpoint that you can do to identify what's causing this as the network traffic is not even getting there.  So the question is really unrelated to SQL Server as far as I can tell.  It is a general question of how to troubleshoot network traffic not making it between endpoints.  You would basically need to do a network trace on every interface that it passes through and inspect the traces at the time the error occurs.  If they are VMs on the same host, then it has to be a VM software issue.  If the SQL Server is a VM, was it paused for a snapshot?

Comment: Thanks for the info, with that I can at least focus on network issues which does eliminate a lot of other possibilities. It's in Azure so VMs are all on different machines in the same data center or at least region (with 10km of each other). They have quite a bit of troubleshooting tools built in, so I'll start there.